# tab.js:155 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined

Tags: jquery

I created a multi step form using bootstrap and jquery.

When I click in some button to go to the next step it appears this error on the console:

```
tab.js:155 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined
    at t.a._activate (tab.js:155) (if (container.nodeName === 'UL')
    at t.a.show (tab.js:120)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (tab.js:249)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.t._jQueryInterface [as tab] (tab.js:236)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (tab.js:266)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
a._activate @ tab.js:155
a.show @ tab.js:120
(anonymous) @ tab.js:249
each @ jquery.min.js:2
each @ jquery.min.js:2
t._jQueryInterface @ tab.js:236
(anonymous) @ tab.js:266
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

Do you know how to fix this error?

The JS code for the navigation buttons:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        $('a.nav-link').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
            var $target = $(e.target);
            if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        $(".next-step").click(function (e) {
            var $active = $('.nav-pills li a.active');
            $active.parent().next().removeClass('disabled');
            nextTab($active);
        });

        $(".prev-step").click(function (e) {
            var $active = $('.nav-pills li a.active');
            prevTab($active);
        });

        function nextTab(elem) {
            $(elem).parent().next().find('a.nav-link').click();
        }
        function prevTab(elem) {
            $(elem).parent().prev().find('a.nav-link').click();
        }
    });


</script>
```

Comment: This may be a late reply thought, but what's your bootstrap version?

Comment: Same problem under bootstrap 4.0.0.

Comment: Could you add more of tab.js for us to review?  Specifically, the line numbers the errors occur on.

Answer (score 5):

Had the problem some minutes ago and realized that a little change of in my markup fixed it.

1. Use the ul>li>a markup structure
2. Make sure your parent UL has the class "nav" apparently all Nav items in bootstrap 4 must have the .nav class https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23594

Comment: yup, needed to have a parent that used class="nav"